# The right way to express continuing process in passive form

Tags: passive-voice, present-tense, progressive-aspect

Which sentence is correct if my intention is to express the continuing process : English is studied by me for several years or English has been studying by me for several years.

Comment: Neither of them. **English has been studied by me for several years** or a better phrasing would be **I have been studying English for several years** or **I have studied English for several years**.

Comment: Possible correction of the first one: _English **was** studied by me for several years before I finally dropped it._

Comment: @MvLog Thanks. The question was asked about continued process of learning. Those who dropped it didn't ask anything at all

Comment: @Andrei _Continuing process_ not _continued_ if it is still going on. _Don't ask_ not _didn't_ if you're making a general statement.

Comment: It is a very unlikely sentence. No one in her right mind would say that. Imagine saying: Bread has been being baked by him for five years. It's grammatical but one would say: He's been baking bread for five years.   These types of sentences in the continuous passive are not commonly structured like yours; That said, one can do it:  English has been being used by us for various reasons. Machines have been being cleaned now for five hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> English has been studying by me for several years.

This is not valid English: *has been studying* is active voice and will not sustain the agentive complement *by me*.

> English is studied by me for several years.

This is formally acceptable, but there is a semantic disconnect between present-tense *is studied* and the temporal *for several years*. It is quite possible for a 'gnomic' present to refer to an indefinitely long timespan, but that timespan is taken to extend equally far into the past and the future, while *for several years* implies that the span has come to an end. The only context in which this sentence might appear is a narrative cast in the 'historical present': perhaps a chapter heading in your autobiography!

> English has been studied by me for several years *(suggested by Weather Vane)*

This is possible: it might be a continuative perfect, mentioning an activity which has continued right up to the present. Equally, however, it might be an existential perfect, mentioning an activity lying entirely in the past: that activity would bear perfective aspect and thus exclude your requirement that it express processuality. There is consequently a growing tendency in present-day English to cast continuatives in the progressive perfect:

> English has been being studied by me for several years.

All of this begs the question of whether *I have been studying English* can be  meaningfully cast into the passive at all. What passivizable thematic role does *English* play here? A field of study is not a Patient or a Theme, unless the Agent effects (or at least seeks to effect) some change of state in it, as in *This problem has been studied by me several years*—and that doesn't really work in the progressive. *English* is I think more like a Location or Scene, and it's very doubtful that that can be passivized:  **The airport has been departed from*! I cannot imagine circumstances in which such a sentence would actually be uttered.

Comment: I would say that none is valid. English has been studied by these students, yes, But nothing with I or me. It is not a grammar issue. it's a: But who- would-even-say-that issue?

Answer (score 2):

*English has been studied by me for several years.*

This is correct but very unnatural sounding.